# Cannot ping wlan until I plug a cable...?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 18.04

I have a brand new Cirrus7 NimbusV2 and I love it.

But I am facing the following problem: I cannot ping the box on its wlan IP address until I plug an ethernet cable.

Here is the output of `ip addr`:

```
4: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.232/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 441sec preferred_lft 441sec
    inet6 fe80::bf4:2f5d:5c8a:d8a1/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When no eth cable is plugged, ping fails:

```
ping 10.0.0.232
PING 10.0.0.232 (10.0.0.232) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.232 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2050ms
```

As soon as I plug a cable on one of the two eth interfaces, it works:

```
ping 10.0.0.232
PING 10.0.0.232 (10.0.0.232) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.232: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.232: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=20.6 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.232 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.158/17.405/20.653/3.250 ms
```

Of course, the eth interface is given another IP, in case you wonder:

```
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.230/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft 562sec preferred_lft 562sec
    inet6 fe80::9610:c9b9:a44f:ea73/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And as soon as I unplug the cable, connection on wlan fails !

Does anyone have an idea about how the magic happens ? (maybe its NM related...)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found the problem, and the solution to my own question.

The problem was **power management** on the **wifi** interface. So it was sleeping after a short while, and did not respond to ping.

The solution is to edit `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and set `wifi.powersave = 2` (disabled).

Now I can ping the box anytime.